# Springdocs: Specifying an explicit type for Paged responses

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc

I'm working on a "global search" for my application.
Currently, I'm using hibernate-search to search for instances of multiple different objects and return them to the user.
The relevant code looks as follows:

```java
Search.session(entityManager)
      .search(ModelA.classs, ModelB.class)
      .where(...)
      .sort(...)
      .fetch(skip, count);
```

Skip and count are calculated based on a Pageable and the result is used to create an instance of Page, which will be returned to the controller.

This works as I'd expect, however, the types generated by swagger-docs obviously doesn't know, what the type within the Page is, and therefore uses Object.
I'd like to expose the correct types, as I use them to generate the types for the frontend application.

I was able to set the type to an array, when overwriting the schema like this:

```java
@ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(anyOf = {ModelA.class, ModelB.class}))
public Page<?> search(Pageable pageable) {
```

However, this just disregards the Page and also isn't correct.

The next thing I tried is extending the PageImpl, overwriting the getContent method, and specifying the same schema on this method, but this wasn't included in the output at all.

Next was implementing `Page<T>` myself (and later removing the implements reference to `Page<T>`) and specifying the same schema on `getContent`, `iterator`, and the field itself, but also to no effect.

How do I tell spring-docs, what the content of the resulting Page might be?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when trying to solve a similar problem
Inspired from this thread [Springdoc with a generic return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732267/springdoc-with-a-generic-return-type) i came up with the following solution, and it seems to apply to your case also. Code examples are in Kotlin.

I introduced a stub class that will just act as the Schema for the response:

```
private class PageModel(
  @Schema(oneOf = [ModelA::class, ModelB::class]))
  content: List<Object>
): PageImpl<Object>(content)
```

Then i annotated my Controller like this:

```
@Operation(
  responses = [
    ApiResponse(
      responseCode = "200",
      content = [Content(schema = Schema(implementation = PageModel::class))]
    )
  ]
)
fun getPage(pageable: Pageable): Page<Object>
```

This generated this api response:

```
"PageModel": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "items": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ModelA"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ModelB"
            }
          ],
          "type": "object"
        },
        "type": "array"
      },
    ... -> more page stuff from spring's PageImpl<>
```

And in the "responses" section for the api call:

```
"responses": {
      "200": {
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PageModel"
            }
          }
        },
        "description": "OK"
      }
```

All generated openapi doc is similar to the autogenerated json when returning a Page, it just rewrites the "content" array property to have a specific type.

Comment: That looks like what I would expect; thank you very much! Will give it a try later on