# swagger page<T> response no content

Tags: java, spring, swagger

page response no content

say A hack around this would be to create a new class to wrap that type: but page -> package org.springframework.data.domain;
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732267/springdoc-with-a-generic-return-type)

```
@PostMapping("/friend-request")
@Operation(security = {@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearer-key")},
        summary = "...", description = "...")
public ResponseEntity sendFriendRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        @RequestBody RequestFriend requestFriend) {
    String token = getTokenByReqeust(request);
    String checkId = tokenProvider.getCheckIdFromAccessToken(token);
    friendService.createFriendRequest(checkId, requestFriend.getReceiverId());
    return responseApi.success("...");
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyvL1.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.